# A PHP program access a website timout

Tags: php, timeout

My PHP program access a website which is very slow to open, therefore I get a warning message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mezi.php on line 155.

Line 155 code: `$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');`

My question is: how to increase time allowed to wait for slow website? I have already increased allowed execution time by adding `set_time_limit(100);` to my code. But this does not help.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a socket session that's being created behind the scenes, therefore the correct value in `php.ini` would actually be

```
default_socket_timeout
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am new to PHP. Do you mean I need to tweak system variable "default_socket_timeout" value in php.ini on the server?